# Profiling and optimising PHP / MySQL websites

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization, lamp

I have a server (VPS) that hosts numerous PHP / MySQL websites.  Most are quite similar in that they are all hand-coded websites serving text and images from MySQL databases.

Server traffic has increased a fair amount recently and the server is experiencing some slow down.  As such I want to try and identify bottle necks in the server so that I can improve the server's speed.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this? I have setup timing scripts on some of my larger sites to see how long it takes for the webpages to be created but its always a really low figure.  According to the server stats the main issue seems to be CPU / MySQL usage.  Is there anyway to identify queries that are taking a long time?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: traffic increase usually lead to server load, so what is the problem? And explain the **fair amount**

Comment: Uhm its over 1million impressions a month.  And no problem, its good, but I want to optimise my site rather than just buy a bigger server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way! MySQL has a built-in feature for this. [You can set up a log file to log slow queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).

Other general advice would of course be to use `EXPLAIN` on common queries and check if everything is indexed properly.

Answer (score 10):

If youre using mysql >= 5.1, you can use `mysql_query("set profiling=1");` in your script, like this:

```
mysql_query("set profiling_history_size=100");
mysql_query("set profiling=1");

....
....
any mysql query
....
....

$rs = mysql_query("show profiles");
while($rd = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
    echo $rd->Query_ID.' - '.round($rd->Duration,4) * 1000 .' ms - '.$rd->Query.'<br />';
}
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: What kind of result would I get from that? Can it be used around multiple queries or just one?

Comment: Multiple query: Star the profilling at the top of your script, and print the result at the bottom of your script.

Answer (score 4):

Start from the firebug's Net tab and see what resources have slowest response.

But I can tell you even without any profiling that

> serving ... images from MySQL databases

being at least one of the reasons.

Comment: Hey thanks but the actual HTML construction of the sites is fast, everything is hand coded and very lean.  The issue, I believe, is in the backend scripts that I dont know how to profile :)

Comment: what are these "backend" scripts? you didn't mention them. also, "everything is hand coded and very lean" does not sound as a profiling resilt.

Comment: By backend scripts I mean the PHP / MySQL.  The HTML, CSS and javascript is very lean.  The issue is with server performance not the webpage content itself.

Comment: it is not backend scripts it is called frontend scripts. With firebug's Net tab you can determine which is slowest. A good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

XDebug has a profiling tool that gives you a lot of information about the bottlenecks in your code. Check out http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler.